# How to automatically detect cut-off (too long) strings in localized Qt applications?

Tags: qt, localization, internationalization

In my Qt application I have many different screens with localized widgets using Qt's tr(). To determine if a string is displayed correctly without being cut-off we have the following workflow:

1. English version is checked by the developer implicitly
2. Translated versions are reviewed manually by native speakers using automatically generated screenshots or the application directly

The problem is that a manual review process cannot cover 100% of the strings since some texts are only displayed for certain errors or scenarios that cannot be easily reproduced by the reviewers. Languages such as Russian or German tend to have much longer words than English.

**Which approaches do you know to check cut-off/too long strings in any of the translated versions of the software?**

Approaches that I thought about but was not satisfied with:

- I could loop over all widgets in the application automatically and check the maximum width of the labels. I could then use the font metrics to render the strings off-screen in all languages and compare the maximum width with the actual needed space after rendering and create a log which contains the widget names and strings that fail. The problem is that a lot of the strings are assigned dynamically so I would need to know all permutations of possible texts of all labels.
- I could (manually?!) define a maximum pixel count for each string and hand this information to the translator. Then the translator could use the exact same font and the exact same font size, render the translated strings and compare the pixel amounts. This approach requires the developer to specify the maximum pixels for each location on the screen which might not even be possible if dynamic layouts are used. It sounds like a tedious job.

Comment: Normally GUI should be designed and implemented in the way when it automatically resized so that all text will be properly shown. This can be achieved by properly used layouts. Isn't it so in your application? Besides, even if you know the length of all strings you cannot be sure that they all properly appear on the screen without testing GUI itself.

Comment: @vahancho Well, dynamic layouts are used where possible but in my opinion the problem becomes even worse when everything is dynamic. Imagine a very rare error case where the translated text is way to long which would then mess up the layout on an embedded screen with a very limited display size. How would you track down such scenarios?

Comment: @vahancho I did not include the info about our target platform (limited screen size, many abbreviations even in the English version). So it's not like a website or Desktop application with lots of room, there is also no mouse/pointer. Do you think that I should include this info in my question? I guess it's clear now from our comments :-)

Comment: Yes, it's clear now, thanks. I thought of a desktop application, indeed. Well, if English is OK, I would take it as a baseline. Than I would extract all strings: translated and original, from translation file(s) (TS files are in XML format, I guess), calculate the length of strings for the given font and screen resolution and, if translated text is longer than its English version, verify that cases manually on GUI (or using GUI automation tools).

Comment: @vahancho That's worth a thought! Unfortunately English is one of the shortest languages people use. Russia has usually factor 2, German 1.6, French, etc. somewhere around 1.3. So in our current software almost all translated terms would fail the test which means that we would need to check them manually. Your approach would be amazing if we developed the Russian version first ;-)

Comment: I understand. From the another hand it's up to you how to define criterion (not necessary to develop on Russian too). You can take Russian strings as a baseline as well. Even it's needless to bind to a single language - just find the maximum string length that still fits the GUI.

Comment: Jep, you are right. Maybe someone knows another more automated Qt-like approach but I think that you set me onto a promising track :-)

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to write a function that iterates over all widgets of a given type and check the text size.

```
QList<QLabel *> labels = rootWidget->findChildren<QLabel *>();

for (auto label : labels)
    check(label);
```

The check can be done using `QFontMetric`:

```
void check (QLabel *label)
{
    QFontMetrics fm = label->fontMetrics();
    bool ok = fm.width(label->text()) <= label->width();
}
```

The `check()` function may need to be overloaded for different types of text drawing widgets. You may also want to adjust the comparison to account for more things (margins, padding, etc.).

If you use a Qt Quick interface it might be possible to do something like that, but it will be a bit harder because you might have to search for dynamic properties declared in QML.

For widgets in dynamic layouts this require having the evaluated widget shown at some point so that the final size of the widget is known.
For Qt Quick, you need to have the QML file loaded and the item instantiated to even retrieve its parent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and code! It's basically the first approach I described in my question. My concern here is: "The problem is that a lot of the strings are assigned dynamically so I would need to know all permutations of possible texts of all labels." Do have any thoughts on that as well?

Answer (score 0):

I researched different approaches outside the Qt-domain and found the following:

- [OneSky](https://support.oneskyapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000933087-Introduction) is a company/product that helps to manage translation processes. They basically offer a [character limit](https://support.oneskyapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/206829247-Setting-length-limit-character-limit) which does not work since the width of a rendered string depends on the used font and language, e.g.: "iiii" and "WWWW". In Russian it seems that almost all letters take up much more space so a character-limit is in practice of no good use. In addition OneSky support a screenshot feature to send them to the translators (which again is a manual review process).
- In [What’s new in localization in Xcode 9 and iOS 11](http://www.ibabbleon.com/copywriter-translator/2017/06/whats-new-in-localization-in-xcode-9-ios-11/) they also mention that screenshots should be used to send them to translators.
- [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/TestingYourInternationalApp/TestingYourInternationalApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH7-SW1) mentions pseudo-language testing which simply uses an artificial langauge with too long terms (e.g. factor 2).
- And of course a list of [best practices](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-tips-and-best-practices-for-software-localization/) that might be true but can only help to improve an automated translation process.

So it seems that there is no standard-way of implementing an automated translation process when it comes to cut-off strings. Developers can only implement tools to aid the translators. I think that there cannot be a fully automated solution due to:

- **Context** that can often not be described perfectly with a simple comment for the translator without a screenshot
- **Dynamic layouts** that still do not protect one from too long strings everywhere
- **Fixed layouts** that of course do not protect one from too long strings (but at least make it easy to find wrong terms)
- **Esthetics** because fitting strings don't necessarily look pleasant to the viewer. It could still look "crammed" in some languages.